# Why does ubuntu's "move to trash" option not exist?

Tags: 20.04, trash

I tried to delete the file on the secondary hard disk, but there is no "Move to trash" option. What is the solution?[image]

Comment: What version of Ununtu?

Comment: 20.04 LTS Ubuntu version

Comment: Maybe there is no Trash in that filesystem

Comment: How to fix it?..

Answer (score 1):

Is there any `.Trash` or `.Trash-1000` or similar folder on the root of that drive? If so try to delete that folder first and then reboot.

```
sudo rm -rf /media/XXXXXXXXX/.Trash-1000
```

Where `XXXXXXXXX` is the mount point of your secondary hard drive.

**Note:** Folders and files starting with a `.` are hidden in the Files app. To toggle visibility of such files and folders press `CTRL+H`.

*(This is assuming you already have the appropriate permissions to write to that disk.)*

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean in the "XXXXXXXX" section it should be filled with a storage name or something like / dev / sda1

Comment: Just look at the root (top folder) of your secondary hard disk and see if you find the `.Trash-1000` folder there or not.

Comment: Yes I saw it, what should I do?

Comment: Just delete it, although you may not be able to delete it from the File Manager. So just right-click **on an empty space** next to the `.Trash-1000` folder and select "Open In Terminal" and then enter the command `sudo rm -rf ./.Trash-1000` and it will be deleted.